# Updating Excel file with Peoplesoft data

Tags: excel, peoplesoft

As a PM i am required to steer my team on the hours they spend on my projects.

the hours are reported in PeopleSoft.
Is there a way to extract the hours reported in the P/S HR module to an excel file?

should something be programmed in Excel any and all suggestions are welcome

Duco

Comment: PeopleSoft is an Oracle database.  If you have access(to the DB not MS Access), you can pull the data using the Oracle ODBC driver.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the PeopleSoft system, you could use the delivered reporting functionality.  The menu path for queries is:Reporting Tools -> Query -> Query Manager.  Query manager will let you run a query and save the results to an excel file.

However you likely need to contact your IT department to write you a query that generates the data for the people you are wanting or write the query yourself.  I would strongly recommend contacting your IT department to write the query or they may already have an existing query you could use.